# Amazon S3 ECL Provider

Tags: 2013, web8, ecl, s3

I'm trying to create an S3 ECL Provider...But I'm not sure how to create the connection. I'm on .NET Framework 4.5.2 and SDL Web8.1

I have two possible ways:

1)

```
AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config()
{
      ServiceURL = serviceUrl,
};

S3 = new AmazonS3Client(
      mountpointConfig.Element(S3AccessId).Value,
      mountpointConfig.Element(S3SecretKey).Value,
      amazonS3Config
);
```

2)

```
        AmazonS3Client S3 = new Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client(
        config.Element(S3BucketName).Value,
        config.Element(S3SecretKey).Value,
        config.Element(S3AccessId).Value)            
        config.Element(FullBucketUrl).Value
        );
```

I'm trying to follow the article [here](https://vikaskumarblogs.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/creating-sdl-tridionweb-ecl-provider-for-aws-s3-bucket/) but there are errors and empty gaps...like

In S3Item.cs I see something that seems to be a constructor but named S3MediaSet, Is that intended to be a constructor (and should be named S3Item) or a method that should have return type?

Also in S3Provider I don’t get S3 propery (in Initialize method) of what type is it, AmazonS3Client? If so then S3Content.GetViewItemUrl has a call to S3Provider.S3.GetMediaUrl which doesn’t exist in AmazonS3Client.

Does someone has a complete sample code on how to create an S3 ECL Provider for Tridion that can share please?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

This is the log I'm getting

2017-07-19 16:29:38,960 [37] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
2017-07-19 16:29:38,960 [37] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
2017-07-19 16:29:42,621 [37] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process request for command 'GetList' id='tcm:0-287-1'
2017-07-19 16:29:43,379 [37] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process responce for command 'GetList' id='tcm:0-287-1'
2017-07-19 16:29:46,219 [36] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process request for command 'GetList' id='ecl:287-s3-root-mp-mountpoint'
2017-07-19 16:29:46,715 [37] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process request for command 'GetList' id='ecl:287-s3-root-mp-mountpoint'
2017-07-19 16:29:46,755 [37] ERROR UI.Model - 
System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id s3.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
2017-07-19 16:29:46,756 [36] ERROR UI.Model - 
System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id s3.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
   at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
2017-07-19 16:29:47,125 [36] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
2017-07-19 16:29:47,125 [36] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
2017-07-19 16:29:53,854 [36] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
2017-07-19 16:29:53,854 [36] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'

Comment: Hi Polonnskyg- the S3Item.cs does not have constructor and does not need one. S3 class is sample model class with some properties. I would see if I can share the code somehwere.. the code in blog is just to make understanding on how it works.

Comment: Hi @VikasKumar thx for replying...Our main problem now is that after creating the mountpoint we're getting:
ERROR UI.Model - System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id s3.

Any idea what might be it?

Comment: @VikasKumar And regarding the S3Item.cs, you have this ** public S3MediaSet(IEclUri ecluri, S3Info info) : base(ecluri, info) ** but I don't get that base(ecluri, info) , since it's inheriting from classes that doesn't have S3MediaSet method

Comment: Look at the code here - https://github.com/vikaskumar185/S3ECLProvider

Comment: About - "Failed initializing the External Content Library with id s3" - you might want to check the ecl.xml. The id is in ecl.xml. Debug your code for Initialize() by attaching it to servicehost.

Comment: Use better examples
https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7

Comment: @VikasKumar The initialization error was that I was adding Tridion dlls in the output folder so Tridion files were not picked up but mine. I'll check your complete code, yesterday I was having a problem when trying to get the files, I received an error regarding the key not found (S3 key). Please create an answer in SO so I can set it as the correct answer. Thx!!!

Comment: @YuriBondarchuk I've used that one, but with S3 is not exactly the same...

Comment: Cool, let me know if you still need help.

Comment: @VikasKumar One question, If I use the code as it is, I'm getting that no endpoint nor serviceURL was specified when creating AmazonS3Client, so I created a config object with the ServiceURL pointing to the FullBacketURL. Now, in GetDirectories() I'm getting in S3.cs, method s3Root.GetDirectories()) -> "The specified key does not exist". Any idea what this might be? I've followed your directives on xml.

Comment: Check for the s3 url based on region, they sometime don't seem right. First try to connect to s3 and then ho on with ecl implementation. The implementation works fine you might need to tweak a bit with s3 connection as they might be diff in your case based on aws security features.

Comment: If you can make your connections right the code works fine.

Comment: @VikasKumar Working! I needed to specify Amazon.EndpointRegion in the AmazonS3Client constructor. Thx!!! One question..Is this test code that I can use and play with or Is it any licensing?

Comment: Its not licensed though i would suggest to use my implementation for learning purposes.

Comment: @VikasKumar Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the discussion on the  question has given bit of clarity, but for sake of answer I would put below points:

1. Make sure you have proper connection to S3
2. Use the code and help from [here](https://vikaskumarblogs.wordpress.com/2017/04/06/creating-sdl-tridionweb-ecl-provider-for-aws-s3-bucket/)
3. Code works fine so focus on debugging first when you see error.

Comment: Do you know if there is any number of items that above that number is really slow? We've tried with 400 files (less than 40KB each) and is really slow, like 30 seconds at least to bring them)

Comment: Well for 400 or more it might be unless you enumerate them. Try using enumerated methods to get in call list and use pagination. If you have read my blog I have mentioned keeping 100 images at least about to it per folder makes it faster, however you do what you need to do, so use enumeration.

Comment: one last question, When in S3.cs, method public S3Info GetMediaInfo(IEclUri eclUri) is called with a folder s3Obj = s3Client.GetObject(request); throws key not found (it does work for files. Do you know why?

Comment: Because files and folders in aws acts as key. There are no such concepts of file and directories in aws, you actually interpret them based on trailing '/' slash. So method takes key and that key could be anything.